# While loop not executing else statements in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and i have written the code below but there are 2 to 3 problems with it .

1. While loop does not print the else statement when
   ever i enter 6 or 7 it again asks for input .
2. Once while loop was started for one function for
   example addTwoNumbers it would remain in it that i have handled
   through the return is there any other way to do that also ?

   Thanks

   `def main():`

   ```
           choice=menu()

           while choice!='5':
                   num1=int(input("enter first number: "))
                   num2=int(input("enter the second number: "))


                   if choice=='1':


                           total= addTwoNumber(num1,num2)
                           print("sum of two numbers is: ",total)
                           conti=contin()
                           return

                   elif choice=='2':


                           sub=minTwoNumber(num1,num2)
                           print("num1-num2",sub)
                           conti=contin()
                           return
                   elif choice=='3':

                           quo,remain=qrTwoNumber(num1,num2)
                           print(quo)
                           print(remain)
                           conti=contin()
                           return
                   else:
                           print("Wrong Option.Kindly choose between 1 to 4 : ")
                           choice=menu()






   def menu():

           print("Welcome to the menu.Kindly choose from below: ")
           print("1.To add two numbers: ")
           print("2.To subtract two numbers: ")
           print("3.For quotient and remainder :")
           print("4.Exit Program")
           opt=input("Enter number between 1-4")
           if opt=='4':
                   print('Exiting program')

           return opt
   def addTwoNumber(n1,n2):

       sum=n1+n2
       return sum
   def minTwoNumber(a1,a2):

       minus=a1-a2
       return minus
   def qrTwoNumber(q1,q2):

       quotient=q1//q2
       remainder=q1%q2
       return quotient,remainder
   def contin():

           con=input("Do you want to continue (Y/N):")
           if con=='y' or con=='Y':
                   choice=menu()
           else:        
                   print("Exiting program")
                   sys.exit()


   main()
   ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Usually you'll get better responses if you post only the parts of your code that you think are relevant. Try to narrow down the problem as much as you can, then ask about that specific part.

Comment: instead of `while choice!='5':` it should be `while choice!='4':` right?

Comment: `if con=='y' or con=='Y':
                choice=menu()` It should be `if con=='y' or con=='Y':
                main()` it will fix your issue..

Answer (score 0):

These are some mistakes:

- `while choice!='5'` should be `while choice!='4'`
- You are returning after if statements. That exits from the loop.
- In that if statements you are calling `contin()` but storing the return value in `conti` but you are not using it. It should be `choice`.
- In the `contin()` you are not returning the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are related, the control flow of your program is mixed up, and you need to be aware of variable scope. As a short example your menu is doing this:

```
def main():
    choice = 5
    print(choice)

    contin()

    print(choice)


def contin():
    choice = 10


main()
```

It sets 'choice' in the top `main` function, and then tries to change it later on in the `contin` function. Those are actually two *different* variables with the same name. The variable *scope* is only inside the function where the value was set.

Therefore, since the value of `choice` never changes in `main()`, the while loop can never quit, the math function can never be different, and you are stuck doing the same math function over and over again.

And the way the program needs to work is like this:

```
menu
 -> choice 
   -> numbers
     -> math
 <-
 menu
 -> choice 
   -> numbers
     -> math
 <-
 menu
 -> choice 
   -> numbers
     -> math
 <-
 menu
 # you quit here, and the program exits
```

But your code goes into `conti()` which then goes into `main()` again, so it gets more and more *nested*, like this:

```
menu
 -> choice 
   -> numbers
     -> math
       -> menu
         -> choice 
           -> numbers
             -> math
               -> menu
                -> choice 
                  -> numbers
                    -> math
                      -> menu
                       # you try to quit here but end up
                  choice  #back at this level
```

That means that when you eventually press 7 to quit the menu, instead of exiting the program, you exit the last `conti()` call and are put back up to the top of the while loop, and prompted for more numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the help it explains everything :)

Answer (score 0):

The real issue with your code is that the [control flow](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/contflow.htm) doesn't work how you think it does.

Pretend to be your computer. Take a hard look at your code, looking at it line by line.

1. The first bit of code that is run is `main()`. So look at that function.
2. Inside `main`, you first call your menu and get a number from your user.
3. Next, you set up a loop. As long as this first number from the user isn't `5`, your loop will run. For now, we'll pretend the user entered `1`.
4. Then you get two numbers as input from your user. That works fine.
5. Since they entered `1` as the choice, the condition for your first `if` statement (`choice=='1'`) is true, so the code inside gets run.
6. You `addTwoNumber` function is run, and the returned output is stored in `total`.
7. Next, you call `contin()` and store its output in `conti`. But take a look inside `contin()`, let's go line-by-line in this function.
8. You ask the user if they want to continue, and if they enter `y` (or `Y`), you call `menu()` again and store its output in `choice`, which your loop checks, right? Well, that's not quite right. The thing is, whenever you define a variable in a function, that variable only exists inside that function. **Functions can't see the variables inside other functions** (unless you pass them as parameters, or you use global variables... but you really shouldn't use global variables). So the `choice` variable you're using in `contin` belongs to that function, but there's *another, separate* variable that also has the name `choice` for the `main` function!

To fix this, you can change the `choice=menu()` line to `return menu()`. Then change `conti=contin()` to `choice=contin()`.

Also, you don't need those `return`s after you call `contin()`. If you `return` there, your function will exit, and your loop will stop running.

Here's a portion of your code with the fixes I mentioned. Do you understand why it works? Can you figure out what else has to be changed for everything to be fixed?

```
def main():
    choice = menu()

    while choice != '5':
        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter the second number: "))

        if choice == '1':
            total = addTwoNumber(num1, num2)
            print("sum of two numbers is: ", total)
            choice = contin()

        elif choice == '2':
```

and

```
def contin():
    con = input("Do you want to continue (Y/N):")

    if con == 'y' or con == 'Y':
        return menu()
    else:
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer ill correct them and another thing the while loop does not execute the else statement when ever i enter wrong number it asks me to enter number 1 and 2 after i enter the numbers then it executes the else statement

Comment: Then you can just move that inside the while loop :)